# Why doesn't my meta account show up in my network profile?

Tags: discussion

http://stackexchange.com/users/1445301/joe-king?tab=accounts

My meta account for SO shows up, but not for CV - is there a reason for that ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Meta.StackOverflow is a little different - it's run as a separate site because it's the meta for the whole StackExchange network in addition to SO, and also for some historical reasons.  On the other site metas, the account is a sort of subaccount of the main account, which is, for example, why you don't accrue reputation for upvotes on Meta.CV.

The [blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/new-per-site-metas/) introducing the per-site metas goes into some detail on the subject.

EDIT:

And incorporating Aarthi's comment, which I did not know, on the users page of the per-site child metas, users are listed by their activity, not their reputation.  Which makes sense, as otherwise the users page would just be a replica of the main site page, and not very useful.

Comment: This pretty much covers it. The only thing I would add is that on the "users" page of a "child meta," the users are listed in order of meta *activity* and not reputation.